# How could I get these two curves to blend into each other?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, procedural

I have two curves that intersect each other however this naturally leaves me with unwanted geometry. How can I get them to blend into each other without converting it into a mesh and using a boolean operation? (I.E make it a procedural effect.)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid that wouldn't achieve what I want at all. 1.) Its not a procedural effect that works no matter where the end point of the curve is and 2.) it would cause scale issues. It also would not solve the overlap at all.

Answer (score 0):

### Geometry Nodes

what you are asking is not possible in a nice / effective / useful way in Blender (my opinion).

Even in a mesh version it is very sensitive task - you need to think about topology. You can try Geometry nodes for generative way, but you would deal with topology issue as well.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I would like to ask down-voter - What is wrong with my answer. Thanks